# How can I disallow mypy `type: ignore` comments?

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, typechecking

I would like for `mypy` to ignore or disallow any `# type: ignore` comments.

Is this possible, short of modifying source files to remove the comments?

Looking for the equivalent of [`flake8 --disable-noqa`](https://flake8.pycqa.org/en/latest/user/options.html#cmdoption-flake8-disable-noqa)

#### Context

When we initially started type-checking our code we ignored a lot of type errors in order to bring it under coverage. Now we are ready to rachet up the quality of our typing and want to be able to locally disable all type ignore comments for a particular module (or the whole project).

Somewhat related to [How to check if Mypy `# type: ignore` comments are still valid and required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65579151/how-to-check-if-mypy-type-ignore-comments-are-still-valid-and-required)

[`mypy` command-line arguments docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html?highlight=strict#the-mypy-command-line)

[`mypy` configuration file](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config_file.html)

Edit:
Note, we already make use of the [`ignore-without-code` rule](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/error_code_list2.html?highlight=ignore-without-code#check-that-type-ignore-include-an-error-code-ignore-without-code)

Comment: Can you explain more in what scenario using `--warn-unused-ignores` is not satisfactory? I think I can imagine, but the question would be clearer if you included it.

Comment: Could you explain a reason to do so? Usually `# type: ignore` comment is your friend, not an enemy. If your employees/teammates/... abuse it everywhere, you'd better teach or fire them - people should know their tools. `--warn-unused-ignores` should be sufficient.

Comment: In order to stop accumulating typing-debt we initially were very aggressive about using type-ignore comments in order to bring modules under type-checking coverage. But now we are ready to do a more thorough second pass on certain modules and would like to be able to easily "ignore" these ignore comments. We don't plan on enforcing this `no type ignores` rule in the CI but we want to be able to do this locally.
Also, I should note we already make use of `ignore-without-code` config setting.

Comment: Modifying the source to remove the comments seems like a straight-forward approach to what you are trying to do.

Comment: I would probably just start *removing* the comments, a few at a time, rather than just simulate removing them all at once. Ignoring the comments probably won't tell you anything you don't already know (or at least strongly suspect): that ignoring them will break type checking.